# Move_base PointCloud2

Tags: navigation, pcl, move-base, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error with move_base

```
Client [/move_base] wants topic /zed/point_cloud/cloud_registered to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection.
```

Obviously it does not like PointCloud2. Is this a configuration problem or do i need to do a conversion to Pointcloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272902/move_base-pointcloud2/) by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-13**:
maybe [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/140881/how-can-i-convert-pointcloud2-to-pointcloud/) or [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/27941/strange-sensor_msgspointcloud2-md5-signatures/) question would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a solution, there is a node which has a configurable launch file in order to convert from PointCloud2 to PointCloud or the other way round:
https://github.com/pal-robotics-forks/point_cloud_converter

---

Originally posted by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0